# findOne() query works well on mongo console, but the same query returns nothing in my node.js code

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

I'm developing a simple question-answer system with a mongo database and node.js.

If the user texts an expected question, the system is supposed to find it and give one related answer.

The first I did to try the query in mongo console was:

`db.answers.findOne({"question": "theQuestion"})`

This query returns a document that matches that question.

When I try the same query from node.js, there is no response.

```
MongoClient.connect(MONGO_PATH, function (err, client) {
        let db = client.db("fierobot");

        db.collection("answers").findOne({
            question: "theQuestion"
        }, function (error, response) {
            if (error)
                throw error;
            if (response)
                console.log(response);
            else
                console.log("NO RESPONSE"); // <-- I always get this
        });
    });
```

This is what I am supposed to receive:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d27211a8bd7a75659148866"),
        "question" : "theQuestion",
        "answer" : "theAnswer"
}
```

Comment: you don't have a error. try `console.log(response)` once. and see what is the response.

Comment: @kcsujeet      when I say no response i mean `null`

Comment: Code looks fine. Are you sure both queries are against the same server and database?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I actually use `insertOne()` and `findOneAndUpdate()` methods in the same code and they seem to work properly. But i don't manage data in those, this is the only moment i need to manipulate the data I receive from the database and i'm not being able to do it proper for some reason

Answer (score -1):

```
MongoClient.connect(MONGO_PATH, function (err, client) {
        let db = client.db("fierobot");

        db.collection("answers").findOne({
            question: { $eq: "theQuestion" }
        }, function (error, response) {
            if (error)
                throw error;
            if (response)
                console.log(response);
            else
                console.log("NO RESPONSE"); // <-- I always get this
        });
    });
```

Comment: question: "theQuestion" => question: { $eq: "theQuestion" }. Why?. Use console.log(response) in else condition. see what's happening